# Check if database connection is still alive

Tags: database, delphi, firebird, zeos

I am developping a Windows background service with Delphi 7 and ZeosLib 6.6.5.

This service is going to run 24/7 and interact with a Firebird database (version 2.1) located on a remote server, so I'll need to check if the service is still able to communicate with it.

What is the best way to do so ? Using Ping or PingServer functions from my TZConnection before doing any operations on the database ?

Have a nice day.

Comment: 1) You test that the connection is still valid (somehow), 2) Your network connection breaks, the server disappears, any of hundreds of other things could happen, 3) Your function returns "yes, the connection is still valid", 4) Whatever ran the check goes ahead and now fails *anyway*. So why not skip 1-3 and just write code that deals with (4) since you need to write that code *anyway*?

Comment: Disconnect when you are done, and reconnect when you need the database again. Handle the database errors. This ensures the connection didn't timeout, etc. And handling normal database errors will make it more robust.

Answer (score 1):

use ZConnection.ping to teste your connection, if lost you must use ZConnection.reconnect to keep your session active (i use the same methode in many project)